# How can i use bootstrap theme styles in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-sass

I have a requirement where i need to use bootstrap theme into  my rails project and there might be a change in the theme at any time. So, i would like to know how i can make use of the styles and also make it in such a way that the new styles can be applied easily.

I just saw the `bootstrap-sass gem` and I am not sure of how to import the themes into my rails app. They have said to use

```
@import bootstrap/theme
```

Will this alone be importing all the styles and js files and also i would like to know few other things listed below. Do i need to replace the theme with name of the theme?

Say I have about `100` text fields do i have to apply the class specified in the theme for every text box and if were supposed to change the theme then do i need to change all the text box classes again or is there is some other way to apply the styles easily.

Comment: Yea well you wrote it, you can just create a copy and call those files out of the application.css with require YOURFILE. I haven't used rails 4.1 so far but I've read the release notes and there is a new features where you are able to load specific files for tablet, phones so on.. probably you could also do something with that. Have a look at the asset [assets pipeline](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)